# How to display data from Firestore at struct correctly?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm currently developing an application using `SwiftUI` and `Firebase`(`FirebaseFirestoreSwift`).

When displaying a `View`, I want to get data from `Firestore` and display it, But the data displayed is not correct.

On the screen of the view below, if I enter a title and tap [Add], I expect that the entered content will be saved in the `FireStore` `Collection`, and then all `Documents` in the `Collection` will be fetched and displayed.
But it can not work well.

For example, if I enter data like below:

1. Enter "AAA" and tap [Add] button → AAA will be displayed
2. Enter "BBB" and tap [Add] button → BBB will be displayed
3. Enter "CCC" and tap [Add] button → BBB will be displayed

[image]

Then if I check the data on the `Firebase` console , I can confirm that it is saved as you entered (AAA, BBB, CCC).

How could I solve this problem?

---

Here are the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct GetDataTest: View {

    @State var items:[Item] = []
    @State var title:String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List{
                ForEach(self.items.indices, id: \.self){index in

                    ListRowTest(
                        title:self.items[index].title
                    )

//                    Text(self.items[index].title)
//                        .font(.title)
//                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                }
            }

            Button(action: {
                self.getAllItems()
            }, label: {
                Text("Update")
            })

            TextField("Enter titel",text:self.$title)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

            Button(action: {

                let item = Item(title: self.title)

                self.addItem(item: item){ (status) in
                    self.getAllItems()
                }
                
                self.title = ""
            }, label: {
                Text("Add")
            })
        }
        .onAppear{
            self.getAllItems()

        }
    }

    func getAllItems(){

        self.items = []

        let ref = Firestore.firestore()
        
        ref.collection("Items").getDocuments{
            (snap, err) in
            guard let docs = snap else{return}

            docs.documentChanges.forEach{ (doc) in
                let item = try! doc.document.data(as:Item.self)
                self.items.append(item!)
            }
        }
    }

    func addItem(item:Item , completion:@escaping (Bool) -> ()){

        let ref = Firestore.firestore()

        do{
            let _ = try
                ref.collection("Items").addDocument(from: item){ (error) in
                    if error != nil{
                        completion(false)
                        return
                    }
                    completion(true)
                }
        }catch{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}


struct ListRowTest: View {

    @State var title:String

    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text(title)
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
        }
    }
}


struct Item : Identifiable,Codable {

    @DocumentID var id : String?
    var title : String

    enum CodingKeys : String,CodingKey {
        case id
        case title
    }
}
```

---

```
            ListRowTest(
                title:self.items[index].title
            )
```

If I change the above code as below, it will be displayed correctly.
But I want to use struct as a component, so this method cannot solve it.

```
            Text(self.items[index].title)
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
```

---

Xcode: Version 12.3

iOS: 14.0

Life Cycle: SwiftUI App

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Firebase/Firestore is really dealing with async functions.
So I would restructure your code to use a ObservableObject that encapsulate
the items and the db calls, for example something like this:

```
class ItemsModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items = [Item]()
    private var ref = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func getAllItems() {
        ref.collection("Items").getDocuments{ (snap, err) in
            guard let docs = snap else{return}
            docs.documentChanges.forEach{ (doc) in
                let item = try! doc.document.data(as:Item.self)
                self.items.append(item!)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func addItem(item: Item, completion:@escaping (Bool) -> ()){
        do {
            let _ = try
                ref.collection("Items").addDocument(from: item){ (error) in
                    if error != nil{
                        completion(false)
                        return
                    }
                    self.items.append(item!)  // <----
                    completion(true)
                }
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}
struct GetDataTest: View {
    @ObservedObject private var itemsModel = ItemsModel()  // <----
    @State var title:String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List{
                ForEach(itemsModel.items.indices, id: \.self){ index in
                    ListRowTest(title: itemsModel.items[index].title)
                }
            }
            Button(action: {
                itemsModel.getAllItems()
            }, label: {
                Text("Update")
            })
            TextField("Enter titel",text:self.$title).textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
            Button(action: {
                let item = Item(title: self.title)
                itemsModel.addItem(item: item) { error in
                    // deal with error here
                }
                self.title = ""
            }, label: {
                Text("Add")
            })
        }
        .onAppear{
            itemsModel.getAllItems()
        }
    }
}
```